# existence of solution of Cauchy Problem with parabolic equation

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, fixed-point-theorems

Let $G_0$ be a set in $\mathbb{R}^n$, $n=2,3$, for any factor 
$\alpha >0$ denote 
$\alpha G_0=\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n, x/\alpha \in G_0\}$,
for any $i \in \mathbb{Z}^n$ denote 
$G_0+i=\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n: x-i \in G_0\}$,
$G_0+\mathbb{Z}^n = \cup_{i \in \mathbb{Z}^n} (G_0+i)$.
Introduce two small parameters $\epsilon, \delta >0$ and a great parameter
$\alpha >0$.

Let $\Omega_{\delta}= \delta G_0 +\mathbb{Z}^n$, where 
$G_0$ is a bounded domain with Lipschitzian boundary,
$\Omega_{\epsilon,\delta}= \epsilon \Omega_{\delta}$.

Define a function $q_{\delta}: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ by
$$
q_{\delta}(\xi)
=
\begin{cases}
1, & \xi \in \Omega_{\delta};\\
0, & x \notin \Omega_{\delta}.
\end{cases}
$$
We consider the parabolic equation 
\begin{equation}\label{1}
\dfrac{\partial u_{\epsilon,\delta}}{\partial t} 
- \Delta u_{\epsilon, \delta}
+ \omega q_{\delta}(\dfrac{x}{\epsilon}) u_{\epsilon,\delta}
= f(x,t)
\end{equation}
in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the initial condition 
\begin{equation}\label{2}
u_{\epsilon,\delta}(x,0)=0,
\end{equation}
where $f(x,t) \in C^2(\mathbb{R}^n \times \overline{R}_+)$
is an $1$-periodic function in $x$.

My question is how we can prove the existence of solution of the parabolic equetion wuth the initial condition? I try to use Schauder, but wit no result. Help me please

Comment: Have you tried Fourier transform?

Comment: non, how we can use is to prove existence? Please

Comment: You can take the Fourier transform to both sides, then you will be solving an ODE of the Fourier transform. But I think you at least need some decay conditions on your $f$ such that its Fourier transform is well defined.

Comment: can you give le your solution? Please